# Is there a word/term for a distant acquaintance?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms, generic-term

Let's say I know and have met a person about 2-3 times and we know each other only on first-name basis(a distant acquaintance if it is), and I am trying to contact a mutual friend(a close friend of my acquaintance) on email and want to refer to this distant acquaintance by one word. Is there such a word that doesn't seem like an overkill.

Comment: There is the term *[distant friend](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Distant+Friends)* (based on *distant relative*) but it might sound wrong.

Comment: @ermanen – agreed that it would sound wrong for the current purpose.

Comment: There are a dozen different ways, depending on the nature of the relationship.  "I know him to say 'Hi!'" is one way of saying that you might nod and wave if you pass him on the street.  But because this kind of thing has so many variations, it's unlikely there's a single word you can use.

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of or find a lone word that would work on its own. My thought would be no, there isn't one. I think you might need to stick with a short phrase. (It doesn't seem inconceivable that other languages might have a single word, or there might be a slang term, though I find no hits in my mind or my research.)

Perhaps you're [scarcely](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/scarcely?s=t) acquainted or [hardly](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hardly?s=t) acquainted or [barely](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/barely?s=t) acquainted.

To me [distant(ly)](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/distant?s=t) seems more appropriate for the description of a relation/relative, except that you might have a vague recollection of meeting in the distant past, so that the memory might seem distant.

But a "distant acquaintance" on the pattern of a "distant relative" does have some charm – in fact it sounds a bit tongue-in-cheek.

Comment: Nothing wrong, ended up using distant :) Curious if there is such a term

Comment: Can you provide definitions for the phrases you have suggested please?

Comment: Edited to respond to comments.

Comment: @Slartibartfast – not a bad choice.

Comment: @Christopher, I've now provided links to the dictionary definitions.

Comment: Another variant is casual acquaintance.

Comment: @ab2: Agreed, though a pair could be casually acquainted even if they'd met each other a fair number of times.